# Skipping Incompatible Libraries at compile

Tags: c++, 64-bit, compilation, 32-bit, conflicting-libraries

When I try to compile a copy of my project on my local machine, I get an error stating that it 's skipping over incompatible libraries.  This isn't the case when I'm messing around with the live version hosted on the server at work [it makes perfectly there].

Various other sites have lead me to believe that this might be an environment issue, as I'm developing on a 64-bit distro of Ubuntu and I assume the server version is running on 32-bit.  Nevertheless, after setting my environment variables to:

```
CFLAGS+=" -m32"
CXXFLAGS+=" -m32"
```

I still receive the same compile error of:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /dvlpmnt/libPI-Http.a when searching for -lPI-Http
```

Can haz tutorial?

==**Edit**==

This was the output I recieved when I followed Jonathan's advice:

```
http.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Apparently, the library in question is 32-bit after all?

Comment: Is that library definitely 32-bit? Try `file /dvlpmnt/libPI-Http.a`

Comment: @Rup: that's likely to say 'current ar archive', which is not dreadfully helpful.  You have to get at a file inside the archive, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That message isn't actually an error - it's just a warning that the file in question isn't of the right architecture (e.g. 32-bit vs 64-bit, wrong CPU architecture). The linker will keep looking for a library of the right type.

Of course, if you're also getting an error along the lines of `can't find lPI-Http` then you have a problem :-)

It's hard to suggest what the exact remedy will be without knowing the details of your build system and makefiles, but here are a couple of shots in the dark:

1. Just to check: usually you would add
   flags to `CFLAGS` rather than
   `CTAGS` - are you sure this is
   correct? (What you have may be correct - this will depend on your build system!)
2. Often the flag needs to be passed to the linker too - so you may also need to modify `LDFLAGS`

If that doesn't help - can you post the full error output, plus the actual command (e.g. `gcc foo.c -m32 -Dxxx` etc) that was being executed?

Comment: In addition to this solution, you can add `-Wl,--no-warn-search-mismatch` to your `CFLAGS` , thus these warnings get suppressed.

Comment: Kind of worked for me, but instead of CFLAGS I used LDFLAGS.

Answer (score 16):

Normally, that is not an error per se; it is a warning that the first file it found that matches the `-lPI-Http` argument to the compiler/linker is not valid.  The error occurs when no other library can be found with the right content.

So, you need to look to see whether `/dvlpmnt/libPI-Http.a` is a library of 32-bit object files or of 64-bit object files - it will likely be 64-bit if you are compiling with the `-m32` option.  Then you need to establish whether there is an alternative `libPI-Http.a` or `libPI-Http.so` file somewhere else that is 32-bit.  If so, ensure that the directory that contains it is listed in a `-L/some/where` argument to the linker.  If not, then you will need to obtain or build a 32-bit version of the library from somewhere.

To establish what is in that library, you may need to do:

```
mkdir junk
cd junk
ar x /dvlpmnt/libPI-Http.a
file *.o
cd ..
rm -fr junk
```

The '`file`' step tells you what type of object files are in the archive.  The rest just makes sure you don't make a mess that can't be easily cleaned up.

Comment: Huh, that's weird, this step is now showing me that all the Libraries in question are, in fact, 32-bit.  o__o

Comment: @defaultstring: What is the actual linking command line?  Does it include the `-m32` flag?  Add that as extra information in the question, rather than as an extra comment here, please.