# skipping incompatible libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart

Tags: cuda

When I compile .cu file with nvcc 5.0, the compiler gives me following information.

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib/libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart

It seems either a warning or an error. I don't know what the matter is.

Is there anyone knowing more details about this information?

Comment: Are you trying to compile a 64-bit code? If so, you need to link against the 64-bit version which must be located in `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This warning often happens when trying to link a 64-bit code with a 32-bit library, see this question: [Skipping Incompatible Libraries at compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119714/skipping-incompatible-libraries-at-compile).

You need to distinguish 2 library files:

- `$CUDA_HOME/lib/libcudart.so`, the 32-bit version of the `cudart` library.
- `$CUDA_HOME/lib64/libcudart.so`, the 64-bit version of the `cudart` library.

(in your case, `$CUDA_HOME` is `/usr/local/cuda-5.0`)

Basically, the linker finds the 32-bit library first (`-L` options are searched in order) and returns that warning even if it ends up finding the proper library.

You probably need to add `$CUDA_HOME/lib64` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable before `$CUDA_HOME/lib` so that `ld` can find the proper library for your 64-bit architecture before the 32-bit version.

Comment: Thank you. My working OS is 64-bit, so all my code will be compile and link to 64-bit. It seems strange that the 64-bit CUDA5.0 includes 32-bit librarys.

Comment: On a 64-bit OS, you can also make and run 32-bit applications, so you'd need the 32-bit `libcudart.so` for that.

Comment: I seem to have precisely the same problem.  My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has `lib64` before `lib`, so that doesn't seem to work on my system. Any ideas?

Comment: @ZoëClark: just to be sure, this warning does disappear if you remove the `lib` path from your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, right?