# Makefile opencv stopped working

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, makefile

I have the following Makefile for projects using opencv

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

% : %.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

This worked fine until recently. I now get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcufft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnpps
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnppi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnppc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
```

`pkg-config --libs opencv` outputs:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so 
/usr/lib/libGL.so 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so 
-lcufft -lnpps -lnppi -lnppc -lcudart -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

I have exported the cuda library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64
```

This path indeed contains the libraries:

```
ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
libcublas_device.a   libcudart.so.5.0     libcufftw.so          libcurand.so.5.5       libnppc.so.5.5.22  libnvToolsExt.so
libcublas.so         libcudart.so.5.5     libcufftw.so.5.5      libcurand.so.5.5.22    libnppi.so         libnvToolsExt.so.1
libcublas.so.5.0     libcudart.so.5.5.22  libcufftw.so.5.5.22   libcusparse.so         libnppi.so.5.5     libnvToolsExt.so.1.0.0
libcublas.so.5.5     libcudart_static.a   libcuinj64.so         libcusparse.so.5.5     libnppi.so.5.5.22
libcublas.so.5.5.22  libcufft.so          libcuinj64.so.5.5     libcusparse.so.5.5.22  libnpps.so
libcudadevrt.a       libcufft.so.5.5      libcuinj64.so.5.5.22  libnppc.so             libnpps.so.5.5
libcudart.so         libcufft.so.5.5.22   libcurand.so          libnppc.so.5.5         libnpps.so.5.5.22
```

But I still get the errors. I run opencv 2.4.9 and cuda 5.5. What am I forgetting?

Comment: Have you tried to add the path to cuda library in the Makefile with `-L`? Maybe there is an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904990/what-is-the-difference-between-ld-library-path-and-l-at-link-time

Comment: I now did this: `g++ -L /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64` `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `-o writeFramesMainSimple writeFramesMainSimple.cpp` `pkg-config --libs opencv` and it worked! I still don't get why it stopped working in the first place though, since this is exactly what's in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. According to your link, this should work fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now did this: `g++ -L /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64 pkg-config --cflags opencv -o writeFramesMainSimple writeFramesMainSimple.cpp pkg-config --libs opencv` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for runtime. For compilation you need to use `LIBRARY_PATH`.
Either you export `/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64` to `LIBRARY_PATH` or you add the path to `LIBS` in your Makefile:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64
```

[LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path)

Comment: I exported `/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64` to `LIBRARY_PATH`. Now I get `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/../lib/libcufft.so when searching for -lcufft
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/../lib/libnpps.so when searching for -lnpps
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/../lib/libnppi.so when searching for -lnppi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/../lib/libnppc.so when searching for -lnppc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/../lib/libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080280/skipping-incompatible-libcudart-so-when-searching-for-lcudart

Comment: When instead I export `/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib` to `LIBRARY_PATH` I get `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/../lib/libcufft.so when searching for -lcufft
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcufft.so when searching for -lcufft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcufft` etc.

Comment: Why you have this `/../` in your paths? (/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/../lib/libcufft.so)

Comment: It automatically does that, not sure why though. My path is as I described, either `/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64` or `/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib`.