# What determines if a 32-bit library built on a 64-bit machine needs x86_64 or i386 dependencies?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, g++

I am updating some old C++ projects to build on a 64-bit Linux machine for the first time, and I don't have much Linux experience. I need to build everything as 32-bit binaries, so I'm building everything with `-m32` in the compiler and linker flags. I'm finding that, when linking to their dependencies, some must link with i386 shared objects, and some must link with x86_64 shared objects. If I only include the wrong folder in the linking path (`-L/path/to/wrong/folder`), it says

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible xxx.so when searching for -lxxx
```

which I've come to understand [means the architecture doesn't match what I'm trying to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119714/skipping-incompatible-libraries-at-compile).

The makefiles are nearly identical for two such differing projects, so it doesn't seem like I'm doing something obviously wrong there, and `-m32` appears in the calls to `gcc` and `g++` in the terminal. What could be causing this difference? Should I be concerned, or is it typical for this to happen?

Let me know if more information is needed to answer; I'm not really sure, due to inexperience with Linux and gcc, so apologies in advance.

Comment: If you're building a 32-bit executable, you have to link to 32-bit libraries. If you're getting errors linking to 32-bit libraries, something's gone wrong along the way and you need to give us some more details.

Comment: Run `file` on your `.o` files and it'll tell you whether they're 32-bit or 64-bit.  (If you're building with `-m32`, they *should* be 32-bit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Wyzard and @duskwuff for the tips. I was indeed able to find my problem by using `file` on my .o files. It was just a silly mistake; I had inadvertently reverted the changes I made to one of the projects' `make` files, which included adding the `-m32` flag. I think I misunderstood what the "x86_64" libraries are for, and that confused me (I had assumed it meant "32-bit process for 64-bit machine").

Comment: (I originally posted this in the question comments on Apr 24 '17 and voted to close my own question, but then someone upvoted it long after it was posted, so I guess the question, and the manner in which it was resolved, helped them anyway... Therefore, I'll add this community wiki answer instead.)