# errors during link when building glfw in fedora 27

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, fedora-27

When i try to make the project i get :

```
[pepe@localhost glfw-3.2.1]$ make
....

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../libXinerama.so when searching for -lXinerama
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libXinerama.so when searching for -lXinerama
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libXinerama.so when searching for -lXinerama
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[2]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/wave.dir/build.make:129: examples/wave] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:185: examples/CMakeFiles/wave.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I have xinerama installed but aparently there is no way to link it with make.

Comment: You'll get more help more quickly if you can post these errors in English.

Comment: Ok @Nick i have updated the question.

Comment: Are you [trying to link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3119774/712526) a 64bit program with a 32 bit shared library (or vice versa.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See all of those "skipping incompatible" messages? That is because those libraries have the wrong instruction set.

It looks to me as if it is trying to build 32 bit code against 64-bit libraries. Or vice versa.

Here is what I get on my Fedora system for a library search. You need to install the right "*-devel" package for your build type. You can't have both the i686 and x86_64 devel packages installed at the same time.

```
$ sudo dnf list 'libXine*'
Installed Packages
libXinerama.i686                                            1.1.3-9.fc27                                    @fedora
libXinerama.x86_64                                          1.1.3-9.fc27                                    @fedora
Available Packages
libXinerama-devel.i686                                      1.1.3-9.fc27                                    fedora 
libXinerama-devel.x86_64                                    1.1.3-9.fc27                                    fedora
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do for glfw-3.2.1 :

```
dnf install mesa-libGL-devel.x86_64 libXi-devel.x86_64 libXcursor-devel.x86_64 doxygen libXrandr-devel.x86_64 libXmu-devel libXinerama-devel.x86_64


cd glfw-3.2.1/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ../
make
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm, i guess one of those libraries where missing