# OPENSSL incompatible libssl, libcrypto

Tags: openssl, 64-bit, rhel5, libssl, libcrypto

I am working with openssl library files, anybody could help me with the 64bit precompiled libraries of openssl (RHEL5x64)

I have this warning on the libraries i generated.

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/devlog/prog/toto/libssl.so when searching for -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/devlog/prog/toto/libcrypto.so when searching for -lcrypto
```

Comment: Please post the results for `file /home/devlog/prog/toto/libssl.so` and also post your `ld` command (or compile command if you didn't run `ld` explicitly.)  Also post the results of the `file` command for the object you're trying to link your library with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping Incompatible Libraries at compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119714/skipping-incompatible-libraries-at-compile)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and fixed it by making sure that the architecture of the version of OpenSSL library I was trying to use matched the architecture of the system I was trying to use it on. I had to reinstall OpenSSL with the right version.