# How to avoid these compile errors?

Tags: c, plugins, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a plugin for my game server(more exectly this: [click](https://github.com/pBlueG/SA-MP-MySQL/releases/tag/R37)).
So, when I am trying to compile the plugin in my linux VM(who uses centos 7+) with make command line, I get these errors:

```
Compiling plugin..
Compiling plugin SDK..
Linking (dynamic)..
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a when searching for -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.a when searching for -lboost_chrono
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_chrono
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.a when searching for -lboost_date_time
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_date_time
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a when searching for -lboost_system
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.a when searching for -lboost_atomic
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_atomic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dynamic_link] Error 1
```

My question is how to avoid these errors?
Important note: the tutorial for compiling this plugin(on the main page on github for this plugin) is working for the newer versions for this plugin, but I need the R37 one.
The plugin is write in C and it has a makefile inside.
Thank you.

Comment: Try building using `make VERBOSE=1` so executed commands are printed into the log and post updated log. Right now it is not clear what is going on during build. Also see [Skipping Incompatible Libraries at compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119714/skipping-incompatible-libraries-at-compile).

Comment: I compiled with verbose=1 flag and this is the log...
https://pastebin.com/mv3V5t4G

Answer (score 0):

Install the libboost that goes with the distribution. Whatever you have in `/usr/local/lib` is bad.

Comment: I have installed libboosts but still the same...
(https://www.boost.org/users/download/ and downloaded boost_1_68_0.zip then installed it)

Comment: or should I install on this loacation(/usr/local/lib) these libs? Maybe I don't understand what you say(yeah, I'm newbie at linux and these stuffs..)

Comment: You should install libboost supplied by Fedora.
`yum install boost-devel`

Remove whatever stuff you put in `/usr/local/lib`. Never install anything there unless you can't find what you want provided by `yum`, or you are asking for problems.

Answer (score 0):

Makefile uses `-m32` compilation option for some reason causing 32 bit executable to be produced. So this executable will require 32 bit libraries. So you should either remove `-m32` option or install required 32-bit dependencies.

Comment: Is there any way to install all 32 bit libraries in centos 7?

Comment: @RaphaAxel I guess you need to look for i686 packages, though I building native executable would probably be a better idea.